# How to extend Unity container for automocking?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-container, typemock, automocking

I want Unity to automatically inject mocks for dependencies of SUTs in unit tests.

I'd prefer some kind of [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation to customize (if needed) mocks creation.

Is it possible?

P.S. We use TypeMock

Answer (score 1):

Typemock implemented something similar to what you're looking for.

[Fake.Dependencies](http://tinyurl.com/nxlcjfx) creates a real SUT object, injecting faked parameters to its longest Ctor.
Passing some of the parameters manually is also possible, the rest are automatically faked.

```
UnderTest real = Isolate.Fake.Dependencies<SUT>([args])
```

You can also get a proxy to a fake dependency later in the test.

```
var fake = Isolate.GetFake<F>(real);
```

I'm sure that implementing your own solution is also possible.

Comment: We use property injection with [Dependency] attribute.